# How to know when Store Rating view is closed

Tags: swift, storekit

I'm using `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` to ask the user to rate my app, what I want is to close the current view after user click not now/ cancel/ or submit.

Is there any way to tell that the rating view was closed?